# Why do I get TypeError: file must have a 'write' attribute when using pickle.dump()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I'm currently coding a program that uses facial recognition the facial_recognition library to log into steam using keyboard and mouse macros. A part of my program needs to be saved to a binary file for this to work as expected. I keep on running into all sorts of issues though because I guess in python 3.9 they must've changed the os library a bunch. Here's the code snippet that is causing issues, I will also add in another one I think might cause an issue down the line.

```
     flags = os.O_WRONLY | os.O_BINARY | os.O_CREAT
     fd = os.open(picklepath, flags=flags)
     pickle.dump(self.steamaccounts, file=fd)
     fd.close()
```

This snippet of code is meant to create a binary file or overwrite it if it exists, but I keep getting errors.

```
    try:
         #os.chmod(savedpath, s.S_IREAD)
         flags = os.O_BINARY|os.O_RDONLY
         fd = os.open(picklepath, flags=flags)
         self.steamaccounts = pickle.loads(fd)
         fd.close()
    except Exception:
         self.steamaccounts = {}
         print("No Saved Variables found, continuing!")
```

This snippet of code is the other code I was talking about, this one tries to get the saved dictionary of the previous users who have signed up on the SteamFace application, if it doesn't find the file, it will create an empty dictionary and print to the console that it found no saved variables.

If anybody can help me out with this it'd be very much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You opened the file for reading with `os.O_RDONLY`. Files opened for reading can't be written to. And there is no good reason to use `os.open()` in this case. Use `open()` unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: I put that second bit of code at the beginning of the class intializer, it's meant to be read from not written to. The first bit of code is only ran when a button is pressed.

Comment: BoarGules by the way what's the difference between os.open and open? Is there a built in function for opening files now?

Comment: There has been a built-in method for opening files since Python 1.5.2. The difference is you get back a Python file object, not an OS file handle. And I still say the message about *no write attribute* is because the file is not open for writing.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I hope to be able to make my program downloadable soon for people who want an easier way if they have a webcam to login to steam

Comment: And it may be that `must have 'write' attribute` is because `dump` is expecting a file object not a file handle. File handles don't have 'write' attributes either.